# Can I find if a user subscription is active or not with their email in stripe?

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments, subscription

I am trying to create subscription for my app. My plan is to :

(1)Ask email and phone , save it in their pc.
(2)show details about 2 subscription plans (monthly,yearly)
(3)creating a button for both and sharing subscription link created by stripe (automatically stripe does that)
(4)Check user have active subscription either in monthly or yearly.
(5)if yes continue to app, else show the page with details.

Now I want to know how to know that if that user have active subscription or not with only their email and phone number.(without stripe customer id)

And also I don't want to use html , js in my app that's why I am choosing python for this.

Thanks in advance whoever going to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can [list Customers in the Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list#list_customers-email) and filtering by the `email` parameter. This will give you an array of Customers with that email address.

You can then [list Subscriptions on those Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) using the `customer` parameter.

You can use [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) to iterate through the "pages" of lists you get back from the API (the `limit` parameter on list API calls defaults to 10).

Comment: stripe.Customer.list(email=email) , now I can store this in variable and if active in variable I can continue or else I can show payment page. Thank you so much 